# how to send parameter in post method to api using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have called API in get method and sent the parameters .
Now I want call same API using POST method. How to pass the parameters in javascript..
I have tried

if(XMLHttpRequestObject) {
           XMLHttpRequestObject.open("POST", "Myapi/GetApplicationStatus?ApplicationNo=10011", true);

```
       XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function()  
       {       
            if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4)  
             {  //alert("XML ReadyState");
                if(XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200)
                 {  //alert("XML status");
                     xmlDocument = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseXML;  
                    displayGuest(xmlDocument);  
                 }

            }  
       }  
       XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);  
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sending a POST request, you have to separate the parameters from the URL:

```
var url = "Myapi/GetApplicationStatus";
var params = "ApplicationNo=10011";
XMLHttpRequestObject.open("POST", url, true);
```

and take care about setting some http headers to be set for the request

```
XMLHttpRequestObject.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
XMLHttpRequestObject.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
XMLHttpRequestObject.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
if(XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) {
    alert(XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText);
}
```

}

and finally send the params:

```
XMLHttpRequestObject.send(params);
```

This is an adjusted example from this source you should check: [Send Parameter in post method](http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php)

Answer (score 0):

It rely on the server side , which provide the api. If the server supports POST request, then you can send parameter like in your question.